# calculate period between two monthcalender in C#

Tags: c#, .net, monthcalendar

I have two monthcalender  in C# win application , and I need to calculate the period between then.

I need how many day between two or three month or also years

I need how many month between tow different years.

When I use :

monthcalender.selectstart.month;

this command just calculate the different between months in same year, but when move to next year the value be negative.

and same for days, I use :

monthcalender.selectstart.dayofyear;

Answer (score 4):

monthcalendar.SelectionStart is a `DateTime` structure, which you can do calculations with. Subtracting two dates will result in a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure, which has various properties that should be of use to you.

```
TimeSpan timeBetween = calendar1.SelectionStart - calendar2.SelectionStart;
MessageBox.Show("Days between dates: " + timeBetween.TotalDays);
```

If you wanted to use the Month property of the `DateTime`, you could do something like:

```
DateTime d1 = calendar1.SelectionStart;
DateTime d2 = calendar2.SelectionStart;
ints monthsBetween = d1.Month + d1.Year * 12 - d2.Month - d2.Year * 12;
```

That would leave the days of the month out of the equation though.